# Connecting to servers in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When wanting to connect to a server it says "Invalid name", however the world name appears the same. How do I get my daughter and son to connect?

Answer (score 3):

If your son or daughter's name on *Minecraft Pocket Edition* uses special characters or spaces, it will not work. This may be why you keep getting a message saying "`Invalid Name`".

Here is a list of some characters that ***won't*** work:

```
!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]}\|;:<>?
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I suggest you add this as an answer to the duplicate question, as this information is more helpful than the current answer on that question.